# Extract part of a character using gsub

Tags: r

I want to extract the genres in this character using gsub `A<-("[{'id': 35, 'name': 'Comedy'}, {'id': 18, 'name': 'Drama'}, {'id': 10751, 'name': 'Family'}, {'id': 10749, 'name': 'Romance'}]")`.

How may I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using package `stringr` instead of `gsub()`

```
stringr::str_extract_all(A, "\\w+(?='\\})")[[1]]
[1] "Comedy"  "Drama"   "Family"  "Romance"
```